# class Object is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

I've created my own Vue.js npm library to help me with my personal projects. Everything works fine except when trying to import a `Class`

I've defined the class as so:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default class Foo {
  constructor () {
    ...
  }
}
```

my npm packages.json:

```
"main": "./dist/my-custom-lib.common.js",
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  "build-bundle": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name my-custom-lib ./index.js",
  "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
},
"files": [
  "dist/my-custom-lib.common.js",
  "src/components/*",
  "src/controllers/*",
  "src/mixins/*",
  "src/utilities/*"
],
```

To publish I do a `yarn build-bundle` followed by `npm publish`.

When I try to import it from my other project:

```
import { Foo } from '@username/my-custom-lib'
```

I get the following error:

```
global-plugin.js?3d38:9 Uncaught TypeError: _username_my_custom_lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Foo is not a constructor
```

I'm able to use all other functions/mixins/vue components but not this class.

EDIT: Here is the partial contents of the `common.js` file:

```
var foo_Foo =
/*#__PURE__*/
function () {
  function Foo(router) {
    _classCallCheck(this, Foo);
  }

  _createClass(Foo, [{
    ...source contents...
  }]);

  return Foo;
}();

/* concated harmony reexport foo */__webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "foo", function() { return foo_Foo; });
```

`index.js` which is called as part of `yarn build-bundle` contains the following:

```
import * as components from '@/components'

const VueComponents = {
  install (Vue) {
    for (const plugin in components) {
      Vue.component(plugin, components[plugin])
    }
  }
}

export * from '@/mixins'
export * from '@/utilities'
export * from '@/controllers'

export default VueComponents
```

inside `@/controllers/index.js`:

```
import foo from './foo'

export {
  foo
}
```

Comment: Your class is the default export so you want `import Foo from '@username/my-custom-lib'` (no braces)

Comment: its not the default. just the default of that file but I'm exporting many files. When using without the braces i get the following error: 

`_username_my_custom_lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a is not a constructor`

Comment: _"its not the default"_  it literally has `export default...`. What other files are involved? What exactly does `my-custom-lib.common.js` export?

Comment: I've added an edit to show what the `common.js` includes in relation to the `Foo` class and the `index.js` contents which is used in `yarn build-bundle`. The Foo class is located in `/controllers`

Comment: Feel like pointing out where and how your `Foo` class is included in `index.js`? What's in `controllers`? You can't expect anyone to trace through your code imports when we don't know what's in them

Comment: apologies, just an oversight. I've gone ahead and added that as well

Comment: So you're exporting `Foo` as `foo`. See the problem?

Comment: yikes. I realized that as soon as I posted that O_o. Gonna give it a whirl now. thank you so much for your help and patience~